# Objeto THIS em conflito entre jQuery e classe ECMA6

Tags: jquery, ecmascript-6

Como resolver o conflito entre o `this` de um loop jQuery realizado dentro de um método de uma classe em javascript (ECMA6)?

Exemplo, o `metodoUm` faz um loop utilizando jQuery e para cada iteração do loop, chama o `metodoDois` passando o objeto da interação como parâmetro, logo há dois `this`, um fazendo referência à classe `Teste`, e outro fazendo referência ao elemento encontrado em cada iteração do método `.each`.

```
class Teste{
    metodoUm(){
        $('input').each(function () {
            // $(this) adicionado para referenciar o jQuery
            this.metodoDois($(this)); 
        });
    }

    metodoDois(t){
        console.log(t);
    }
}
teste = new Teste();
teste.metodoUm();
```

Erro apresentado:

```
TypeError: this.metodoDois is not a function(...).
```

Como resolver, ou contornar, este conflito?

Desde já, agradeço pela ajuda.

Comment: @Samir Braga, Obrigado pela ajuda, indicando usar $(this), porém está apresentando o erro: TypeError: this.metodoDois is not a function(…).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como você já está utilizando ES6, você pode fazer o uso de [Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) para preservar referência do `this` e resolver este problema.

Exemplo:

```
$('input').each((i, elemento) => {
    this.metodoDois($(elemento)); 
});
```

O código acima subistituiria o código de dentro da sua função `metodoUm()`.

#### Sobre Arrow Functions

Arrow Functions são uma novidade do ES6 que tem como vantagens uma sintaxe mais curta que a declaração de functions convencional, além de preservar o valor do `this` (ao contrário do formato padrão).

```
function () {
    // declaração de função anônima convencional
}

() => {
    // Arrow Function
}
```

[Você pode ler mais sobre ela aqui](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_arrow-functions.html)

Comment: Se no local do .each eu quisesse utilizar um change ou um keyup... como resolveria o problema do THIS?

Comment: @AllanAndrade A função `.on()` do jQuery sempre retorna um parâmetro com o evento disparado. Isso significa que você ainda conseguiria pegar o elemento de onde o evento disparou sem usar o `this` do jQuery. Exemplo: `$('input').on('keyup', (event) => { console.log(event.target) // input que sofreu o keyup });`.

Answer (score 3):

Acredito que neste caso o ideal seria usar uma variável para guardar a referencia ao `this` da classe

```
class Teste{
    metodoUm(){
        var _this = this;
        $('input').each(function () {
            // $(this) adicionado para referenciar o jQuery
            _this.metodoDois($(this)); 
        });
    }

    metodoDois(t){
        console.log(t);
    }
}
teste = new Teste();
teste.metodoUm();
```

Answer (score 1):

Você poderia chamar a própria *class* `Teste()`, e para seleção do *this* dentro do loop poderia usar `$(this)`:

```
class Teste {
  metodoUm() {
    $('input').each(function() {
      teste.metodoDois($(this));
    });
  }
  metodoDois(t) {
    console.log(t);
  }
}
teste = new Teste();
teste.metodoUm();
```

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda, estou iniciando com ECMA6... desta forma, não estaria criando uma instância para cada item do loop? Isso não comprometeria performance?

Comment: @AllanAndrade, também estou iniciando com ECMA6, rsrs. Mas acho que tens razão, no caso pode usar a variável já declarada. Já que não criaria instâncias novas a cada repetição, e sim usaria apenas uma já criada. Atualizarei a resposta,